# What causes the eureka client in ”DEREGISTRATION“

Tags: java, client, registration, netflix-eureka

When I use eureka client, I just put some information into metadata for other services to obtain, so there is just one class to startup and application.yml, which has been running normally, and suddenly one day my service cannot be found, the maintainer of the eureka server told me that my service was in DEREGISTRATION for a long time today, and only the client can cancel the registration. After I restarted my service, it was indeed normal. But there is no unregistering method in my code, no shutdown has been executed, and there is no message like "Unregistering ..." in the log. I want to know what can caused this "DEREGISTRATION".

By the way, because the server needs "/metrics", the eureka version I use is 1.4.12 and the springcloud version is Camden.SR7

The maintainer of the server gave me the following information
2022-03-11-02.01.0B.169 STATUS_CHANGE up-> OFFLINE
2022-03-11-02.02.28.421 STATUS_CHANGE OFFLINE -UP
2022-03-11-02.05.09.919 DEREGISTRATION